# How to use eloquent to calculate working hours for certain date in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm working on employee attendance project,

I have the following Model : TimeEntry

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------
id        time_start                     time_end                employee_id
----------------------------------------------------------------------
1        2020-07-19 07:39:45           2020-07-19 07:51:07         15
2        2020-07-19 08:17:08           2020-07-19 08:45:49         15
3        2020-07-19 11:23:17           2020-07-19 12:24:03         15
-------------------------
```

employees table:

```
----------------------------------
id        name                 
----------------------------------
1        Jack     
2        Rana           
3        Sara
-------------------------
```

What I want is to calculate the working times and display the total number of hours and minutes the employee worked for every day.

My Attempt:

```
public function hoursSum()
    {

        $no_of_hours = TimeEntry::whereDate('created_at','2020-07-19')
        ->selectRaw('time(sum(TIMEDIFF( time_end, time_start ))) as total')
        ->get();

        return $no_of_hours;

    }
```

The result of the above eloquent query = null

Comment: In your table, there are multiple entries for the same date? . And shouldn't the table have an employer_id, so that it records the data for an employee. It's better if you add the complete schema for the tables which you've used

Comment: If you were to write a raw query and not use PHP Eloquent do you get a result set?

Comment: @Aashishgaba I'm sorry I forgot to add the employee_id to my question and yes there are multiple entries for the same date. I'll edit the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting the OP:

> calculate the working times and display the total number of hours and minutes the employee worked for every day

I assume that you would want employee data and the total time displayed in one table, hence, in one collection. On that assumption, here is one approach:

```
$subquery = TimeEntry::
            select('*', 
            DB::raw('timestampdiff(second, time_start, time_end) as time_difference'))
            ->whereRaw('date(time_start)', '2020-07-19');

$query = Employee::
         select('employees.id as employee_id', 
                'employees.name', 
                 DB::raw('date(time_start) as day'), 
                 DB::raw('sec_to_time(sum(time_difference)) as total_time') )
         ->joinSub($subquery, 'time_diff_table', function($join){
              $join->on('employees.id', 'time_diff_table.employee_id');
           })
         ->groupBy(DB::raw('date(time_start)'), 'employee_id')
         ->get();
```

Here, the sub query is to get the time differences from every time entries. Then, on the main query, time differences are added for each employee, getting the total time for individual employees.

Things to note:

- `timestampdiff(second, time_start, time_end)` calculates the time between two timestamps, giving the result in seconds.
- `sec_to_time` converts seconds in to human readable time format, Hours:minutes:seconds. If you want only hours and minutes, you could apply the `time_format` function
- This query can be used to get the same data for a range of dates as well.

Answer (score 1):

try using SEC_TO_TIME,TIME_TO_SEC [from Date and Time Functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html)

```
 $no_of_hours = TimeEntry::whereDate('created_at','2020-07-19')
        ->selectRaw("SEC_TO_TIME(sum(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(time_end,time_start) )) ) as 'total'")
        ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Indicate that the fields are dates, then use an accessor [(eloquent-mutators)](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor) to calculate the hours:

```php
class Employee extends Model {

// ...

protected $dates = [
    'time_start',
    'time_end',
];

// ...

public function getWorkedTimeAttribute() {
    $diff = $this->time_end->diff($this->time_start);
    return [$diff->h, $diff->m];
}

}
```

Then

```php
$worked = Employee::get(123)->worked_time;
$worked->m;
$worked->h;
```